# How to display multiple values in text area in php?

Tags: php, loops, textbox, concatenation

How do I display multiple values in a textarea field using php?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Generate Random Numbers</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['start']) && !empty($_POST['end']) && !empty($_POST['how_many'])){
            $start = $_POST["start"];
            $end = $_POST["end"];
            $how_many = $_POST["how_many"];
            /* function hw(){
                $how_many = $_POST["how_many"];
                $start = $_POST["start"];
                $end = $_POST["end"];*/

            for ($x=1; $x<=$how_many; $x++){
            $output= rand($start,$end);
            }
        }
            //The rand() function generates a random integer.
            //Tip: If you want a random integer between 10 and 100 (inclusive), use rand (10,100).

        else{
            $start="";
            $end="";
            $how_many="";
            $output="";
        }
    ?>

    Range start: <input type = "text" name = "start" value = "<?php echo $start; ?>"><br>
    Range end: <input type = "text" name = "end" value = "<?php echo $end; ?>"><br>
    How many? <input type = "text" name = "how_many" value = "<?php echo $how_many; ?>"><br>
    Output: <textarea><?php echo $output;?></textarea>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value ="Generate Random Numbers">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As shown below, only 1 output appears in the text area, although it's in a loop.

[image]

Comment: Please add code instead of image.

Comment: __Make an effort__ and paste your code as text.

Comment: If you are talking about the for loop that assigns value to output variable, isnt it that you are overriding "output" value instead of appending to it?

Comment: You'd put more values there by, well, putting more values there.  What have you tried?  What isn't working?

Comment: Before to post a question on SO you should go through [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Finally, if you are sure your question fits the rules, read [How to Ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a useful, well formed/formatted and on-topic question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to employ concatenation inside of your `for` loop (after initially declaring `$output` as an empty string).

I recommend setting some limitations on the user input, so things don't get ridiculous.  You can set these to whatever you wish.

I packed all of the POST data validations and variable declarations into the `if` statement.

I changed the input `type` values to number and implemented the limitations on these fields.

I personally don't like to bounce in and out of php, so I stayed inside of php and wrote echos until I was done using variables.  You are welcome to bounce if you like.

Untested Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Generate Random Numbers</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// subjective developer configurations
$random_min=0;  // developer must set this limit
$random_max=100;  // developer must set this limit
$iterations_min=1;  // developer must set this limit
$iterations_max=20;  // developer must set this limit

echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"",htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),"\">";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'],$_POST['start'],$_POST['end'],$_POST['how_many'])
       && ($start=$_POST['start'])>=$random_min && $_POST['start']<=$random_max
       && ($end=$_POST['end'])>=$random_min && $_POST['end']<=$random_max
       && ($how_many=$_POST['how_many'])>=$iterations_min && $_POST['how_many']<=$iterations_max){
        $output='';
        for($x=0; $x<$how_many; ++$x){
            $output.=rand($start,$end)."\n";
        }
    }else{
        $start=$end=$how_many=$output='';
    }
    echo "Range start: <input type=\"number\" name=\"start\" min=\"$random_min\" max=\"$random_max\" value=\"$start\"><br>";
    echo "Range end: <input type=\"number\" name=\"end\" min=\"$random_min\" max=\"$random_max\" value=\"$end\"><br>";
    echo "How many? <input type=\"number\" name=\"how_many\" min=\"$iterations_min\" max=\"$iterations_max\" value=\"$how_many\"><br>";
    echo "Output: <textarea>$output</textarea><br>"; // you may want to add a conditional rows attribute here to improve display
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate Random Numbers">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```